# Selenium: Is the select window is corresponding to session

Tags: selenium

I want to know how the selenium selectWindow selects the window is it according to session. i.e. If I have two sessions in parallel and both the sessions are selecting pop-up window with same name MyWindow1 started by there corresponding sessions.

Session1 = Opens the new pop-up named MyWindow1
Session2 = Opens the new pop-up named MyWindow1

Then is the selection is according to there sessions please explain

Please clear me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the selectWindow command only selects windows opened from the session where it is issued.  Two Selenium sessions cannot interact with each other.